# How can I get a JSON object out of my ruby application into the terminal?

Tags: ruby, json, bash, terminal

I have a ruby program that I invoke via terminal. When I invoke a particular command, I want to get my JSON response object as a string in the terminal. How can I do this? I've tried storing the output (printed with say_ok) of the command in a bash variable, but have had no luck. I'm not sure what the correct approach is here, so any help is appreciated.

Ruby

```
say_ok response.body
```

Bash

```
JSONOBJECT=$(myrubyapp postandgetresponse)

echo "${JSONOBJECT}"
```

Edit:

Returning the object instead of say_ok seems to of have worked. I will update once verified.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture script output from stdout to bash variable, you can do it like this:

```
% CAPTURE=$(ruby -e "puts 'hello'" | tee /dev/tty)
hello
% echo $CAPTURE
hello
```

Comment: Why is tee necessary?